# Facebook API - Upload photos without grouped in an album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use this code to upload a photo in a Facebook page and it works!

```
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = message;
            parameters.name = name;
            parameters.url = photoUrl;

            dynamic result = fbClient.Post(fbPageId + "/photos", parameters);
```

The problem is that Facebook does not show all the individual photos in the diary of the page, but but it shows the photos grouped in an album.

http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/7033/41802615.png

What it looks like.

http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5474/40129748.png

How it should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable grouping of photos on the timeline](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12785120/disable-grouping-of-photos-on-the-timeline)

Comment: Please _search_ before asking. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=photo+grouping